# Can't install app on Emulator Android API 31. Cause is Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, build.gradle

I just recently started to configure my Android work environment. I am currently using Android Studio 4.0 and have made a blank empty application, however when I start the emulator, the app doesn't get installed I get the error from the following image. [Main description of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdMmL.png)

Here is the full event log from startup to error showcase.
[Full event log of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1f28.png)

And finally the build gradle file.
[Picture of build gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qv7YA.png)

And finally I would like to point out that I have thoroughly checked the manifest file and have concluded that there's nothing wrong in there.

Comment: Hi, can you attach your Manifest file ?

Comment: Also, please post code as text and not as images.

Comment: My manifest is all good, it hasn't been changed since I made the project with an empty activity template.

Answer (score 0):

Change Emulator API to 29 or below might work for Uh. As it works for me after I update my android studio environment.

Comment: My emulator runs on API 30, but I have to downgrade the dependency androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0 to version 1.6.0, otherwise the app doesn't start.